# splash:mouse_click couldn't open pop up window

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape part-time job information from [townwork](https://townwork.net/detail/clc_2578209001/joid_Y00BKDF4/)(A Japanese job information site).
To get the address, I want to open a popup window. Then I started to use [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html).
Although I could open other links and popups using [splash:mouse_click](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-element-object.html#element-mouse-click), I couldn't open the desired pop-up window.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

**The link that I wanted to click.**
[image]

**Desired result.**
[image]

**Target page URL**
https://townwork.net/detail/clc_2578209001/joid_Y00BKDF4/

**Code**

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  local map = splash:select('#jsi-inflow-target > div > dl:nth-child(3) > dd > p > span > a')

  local bounds = map:bounds()
  local x_dif = bounds.right - bounds.left
  
  assert(map:mouse_click({x=bounds.width/3, y=bounds.height/3}))
  splash:wait(1)
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    bounds = bounds
    
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the speed at which this popup opens is the matter.

I found another solution other than opening a popup page to get the address: getting latitude and longitude from the first page.

```
def parse(self, response):
  dt_list = response.css('dt')
    for dt in dt_list:
      if dt.css('::text').get == "勤務地":
        a_tag = BeautifulSoup(dt.xpath('./following-sibling::dd').get()).find('a')
        if a_tag is None:
          continue
        item['lat'] = a_tag['data-lat']
        item['lon'] = a_tag['data-lon']
```